# R time series data aggregation non equal time steps

Tags: r, aggregate, time-series

[image: Example Of Data]

I have the following data that is a time series collection of rain gauge readings.  The Time Stamp is each time the rain gauge makes an increased count, and the Volume is the amount of rain added to the bucket.  I need to aggregate the data into a few different categories of Hourly, 6 Hours, daily, weekly on the total amount of rain added to the bucket.  I tried using some of the other data aggregation methods posted around StachOverflow but they assume normal collection intervals.  I am not very good with R so forgive me if this is a super easy edit to code that has already been posted.

*I know the data is a snap shot from excel but that was just so it would format nicely for visual purpose in this forum because I can't figure out how to post a table*

Attached is the CSV of the data

[Data File Here](http://danthemandonin.com/RStuff/Project1.csv)

Comment: It looks like you have one minute timestep. Why not fill the gaps with 0's and use one of the other methods you found?

Comment: Are you looking for rolling averages or the aggregates from some time-zero? You'll probably want to use some "Cumulative Sums" with tests to define where to break near 6 hours, etc.

Comment: Want to Sum the values, as for filling with zeros there are some with multiple measures per minute like 6:33 and 6:34 at the end.

Comment: @DanTheMan aggregate those first, then fill the gaps. Duplicate timestamps would seem like a mistake anyway. Perhaps you want to consider if those duplicates should be dropped.

Comment: See the `zoo-read` and `zoo-faq` vignettes in the zoo package for discussion of reading in data, aggregating and setting up a grid.  Note that you will need `read.zoo(..., aggregate = sum`)` to take into account the non-unique times.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde they had seconds on them also, they are not duplicates exactly, but the data pull didn't keep the seconds only minutes.

Comment: @DanTheMan then it's only a few lines in base R to sum the dups and fill the gaps. If you update your question with data that we can use (i.e., comma separated text), you'll have an answer in no time.

Comment: @DanTheMan or if this just happens to be the Dan the Man from OOW, feel free to swing by the modeling area. :)

Comment: @MatthewPlourde No not from OOW, I updated the post with a link to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use package Lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
timeseries <- read.csv("project1.csv", sep=",", header=T, dec=".")
timeseries[,1] <- mdy_hm(timeseries[,1])
```

The dates have been converted into POSIXct, which is widely recognized in R.
Next the dates are rounded to the nearest unit. 
The unit can be set to for instance: hours, days, months, etc. 
The rounded dates are stored in a new data.frame which is then joined with the original data.frame. 
The last step is to aggregate the values to the rounded dates.

```
rdate <- ceiling_date(x=timeseries[,1],unit="hour")
temp <- cbind(rdate,timeseries)
timeseries_hour <- aggregate(x=temp[3],by=list(temp[,1]),FUN=sum)
```

Part of the result:

```
head(timeseries_hour)
          Group.1 Ppt..Amount
1 1996-05-02 01:00:00        0.03
2 1996-05-02 02:00:00        0.02
3 1996-05-02 05:00:00        0.01
4 1996-05-02 06:00:00        0.04
5 1996-05-02 07:00:00        0.38
6 1996-05-02 08:00:00        0.13
```

Comment: This would work but it is rounding hours down, so 1:04 and 1:19 are getting counted in the first hour when these are the 2nd hour. Need to figure out how to get it to not round down.  Also "timeseries[,1] <- dmy_hm(timeseries[,1])" keeps erroring out.

Comment: you can try to use 'ceiling_date(x=timeseries[,1],unit="hour")' instead of 'round_date(x=timeseries[,1],unit="hour")'. Can you show what kind of error you get?